# Detecting Outlier from data set by using Tukey method python

Tags: python, statistics, outliers, tukey

I have data frame with shape of 1000 observations ,6 columns

the first four coulmns are int and the last two are string data type.

i need help to find function code that could help me to use tukey method to detect outlier and replace outlier with nan value not removing the outlier.

I tried many code to detect outlier but i am facing error massage because of the string data type in my data frame.

Answer (score 0):

Drop the last two string columns using the `df.drop()` method

```
df.drop(['B', 'C'], axis=1)
```

After identifying the outlier using the Tukey method, use `df[i] = NaN` to replace the value of the outlier.